# unable to insert data that are stored in variables in to an MYSQL database table using python

Tags: python, mysql, flask

am trying to insert the data entered into the web form into database table,i am passing the data to the function to insert the data,but it was not successful below is my code

```
def addnew_to_database(tid,pid,usid,address,status,phno,email,ord_date,del_date):
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='admin_operations', password='mypassword',host='127.0.0.1',database='tracking_system')
    try:
        print tid,pid,usid,address,status,phno,email,ord_date,del_date
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("insert into track_table (tid,pid,usid,address,status,phno,email,ord_date,del_date) values(tid,pid,usid,address,status,phno,email,ord_date,del_date)")
        cursor.execute("insert into user_table (tid,usid) values(tid,usid)")
    finally:
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
```

Comment: am i clear or should i explain in more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the variables as an argument to `.execute` instead of putting them in the actual query. E.g.:

```
cursor.execute("""insert into track_table 
                    (tid,pid,usid,address,status,phno,email,ord_date,del_date)
                  values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", 
               (tid,pid,usid,address,status,phno,email,ord_date,del_date))
cursor.execute("""insert into user_table 
                    (tid,usid) 
                  values (%s,%s)""",(tid,usid))
```

Comment: success,Thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

You should tell us what API you are using and what the error code is. 
You should define the values within the execution, right now within the sql statement as a string they are not referencing anything.

Typically when you use a variable name inside of a sql statement this way, you need to indicate that it is a variable you are binding data to. This might be replacing it with (1,2,3,4..) or (%s,%s,...) that corresponds to an ordered list or using variable names (:tid,:pid,...) that you then define the values of with a dictionary as the second argument of execute().

Like this:

```
track_table_data = [tid,pid,usid,address,status,phno,email,ord_date,del_date]
user_table_data = [tid,usid]
cursor.execute("insert into track_table (tid,pid,usid,address,status,phno,email,ord_date,del_date) values(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)", track_table_data)
cursor.execute("insert into user_table (tid,usid) values(1,2)",user_table_data)
```

or

```
cursor.execute("insert into track_table (tid,pid,usid,address,status,phno,email,ord_date,del_date) values(:tid,:pid,:usid,:address,:status,:phno,:email,:ord_date,:del_date))", {'tid':tid,'pid':pid,'usid':usid,'address':address,'status':status,'phno':status,'email':email,'ord_date':ord_date,'del_date':del_date})
cursor.execute("insert into user_table (tid,usid) values(:tid,:usid)",{'tid':tid,'usid':usid})
```

Comment: values are defined in another method and they passed to this method as parameters

Comment: @learner Sorry, that is clear, I meant on the execution of the insert statement. The way you had it setup, you were not inserting data since within the database the values you inserted were not referencing anything and they were not quoted as values themselves. I will edit for clarity.